# filter_var : validate array of email addresses

Tags: php, validation, email, filter-var

I have a dropdown list where when the user choose All, it will sent email to all recipients that I get from the database. If the user choose 'Other', a textfield will appear which the user have to enter the email address. I would like to validate email that the user entered in the 'Other' textfield is valid. I want to allow user to be able type multiple email addresses, which separated by commas.

This is my form:

```html
<tr>
  <td>To</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td>
    <select name="email" id="email" onchange="if(this.value == 'Other') {this.form['Other'].style.visibility='visible'}else{this.form['Other'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="All">All</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <?php if(isset($error[ 'email'])) echo $error[ 'email']; ?>
    <input type="text" id="Other" name="Other" style="visibility:hidden;" size="46" placeholder="Enter e-mail separated with commas" />
    <?php if(isset($error[ 'Other'])) echo $error[ 'Other']; ?>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is my validation for email:

```html
if($_POST['Other'] != "" && (!filter_var($_POST['Other'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)))
{
 $error['Other'] = "<div class=error>Email entered is not valid.</div>";
}
```

I use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL to validate email addresses. My problem is, If entered one email address, there is no problem, the message will be sent and I received it. But if i entered more than one email, the validation error message will prompt me that the email address I entered is not valid. Can I know why it only works for one email but not for multiple email addresses?

Comment: Explode by comma and validate each

Comment: tried, but i still received the same error. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this you need to do,

```
$emails = 'bill@microsoft.com, test.com, obama@usa.gov';
$emails = explode(', ', $email);
$filterd_emails = array();
foreach($emails as $email){
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error['Other'][] = "<div class=error>$email is not valid Email.</div>";
    }else{
        $filtere_emails[] = $email
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Now you've all validated emails stored in `$filtered_emails`. Here are two different scenarios.

**1**) You want to send emails to all `filtered_emails` (that pass the criteria), no matter how many pass the criteria.

```
//$emails = 'bill@microsoft.com, test.com, obama@usa.gov';
$filtered_emails = array('bill@microsoft.com', 'obama@usa.gov');
```

for that you can use following approach, it'll skip `test.com` and will send email to other two

```
if(count($filtered_emails) > 0)
foreach($filtered_emails as $filtered_email){
    //send email here. email($filtered_email);
}
```

**2**) you don't want to send email any person if any of input emails failed to pass validation.

e.g. `test.com` has failed to pass the criteria, and you don't want to send email at all(to other two `bill@microsoft.com` and `obama@usa.gov`)

in this case,

```
if(count($error['other'])>0){
    //display error and exit
}
```

it's now totally up to you which technique you want to use.

Comment: `preg_split('~\s*,\s*~', trim($emails), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)` is way better as you don't need to use a space after the comma (in fact you can use as many spaces as you want).

Comment: hi, i have changed accordingly, but still could not make it work. I no longer receive the error, but I only able to send to one email.

Comment: you need to call you function to send email inside `else`

Comment: Can i send it after i did all the validation? for example (if(count($error) == 0) only then I want to send it. Or it is not possible?

Comment: @Azie I've updated my answer. Hope this will help now.

Answer (score 0):

The string of emails is converted into an array with the PHP explode function

Then we instantiate a PHP array function and set it to a variable as an empty array

Then we iterate through the array with a PHP foreach loop function

Then we check each email's validity PHP filter_var and FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL functions
filter_var(!filter_var(bill@microsoft.com, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))

```
<?php
  $emails = 'bill@microsoft.com, test.com, obama@usa.gov';
  $emails = explode(', ', $email);
  $filterd_emails = array();
  foreach($emails as $email){
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
       $error['Other'][] = "<div class=error>$email is not valid Email.</div>";
    }else{
       $filtered_emails[] = $email
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation what your code does and how it achieves the intended purpose. E.g. the use of `filter_var` should be explained.